# Django/DRF - 405 Method not allowed on DELETE operation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm working with two dev servers on my local machine (node & django's).

I've added [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to the project to allow all origins & methods (on dev) with the following settings :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = 'ALL'
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
        'GET',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
        'PATCH',
        'DELETE',
        'OPTIONS'
    )
```

I'm getting 405 when attempting DELETE.
Looking at the response headers

```
HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 10:04:43 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

Notice that `DELETE` & `PATCH` / `PUT` are not present in the allowed methods list.

Is there something missing from my configuration ?

Comment: Does your view implement those methods? Are you using ModelViewSet? mixings, ApiView?

Comment: good old `viewsets.ModelViewSet` - tests run perfectly.

Comment: What methods are allowed in your view? Due to docs `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS` define only methods that can be used globally, but not adding it to view automatically. One more thing `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` must be boolean, not string.

Comment: @coldmind - You'r right - it's a boolean - changed it, same result. I guess I'm a bit confused about the difference between global and view level CORS definitions. Do you mind expanding on how can I allow DELETE on a specific view using the `ModelViewset` ? the delete method is working in the test so the view must allow it but the CORS headers are not updated in the response (what I though `djagno-cors-header` is supposed to do ... )

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The response looks *very similar* to that of the **list view** (`/api/resource/`) for a ViewSet. List views only support `GET`, to list all of the objects, and `POST` to create a new object.

`DELETE` requests are only allowed on the **detail view** (`/api/resource/1/`). This is because Django REST Framework needs to know what object you are looking to delete, and this information cannot be retrieved from just the list view.

Comment: Thanks man - That was it. I left out the pk from the url and the request went out to the list rather then the detail.

Comment: If using DRF router module then e.g. `user-detail` supports PUT operation and not `user-list`. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Answer (score 15):

If you need to connect http method DELETE with URL without pk in DRF try this inside of your ModelViewSet:

```
@action(methods=['delete'], detail=False)
def delete(self, request):
    # your code
```

**UPD**: Note that `action` attribute inside of `ModelViewSet` class will be `None` due request. If you check it somewhere, handle not only action name, but request method and request path.

Comment: this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am either getting `403` or `405` error with `delete` request. But adding `@action` decorator is not helping neither is `@csrf_exempt`