# Django HTTP delete method returns 405

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a Django REST Webservice.
If I run the following method (delete), I run into an 405 error

my **view.py**

```
@detail_route(methods="delete")
def remove(self, request, id):
    logger.debug("REST " + request.get_full_path())
    result = HeatingMappingModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    self.response = {"result": True, "data":result}
    return JsonResponse(self.response, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
...
   url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.HeatingMapping.as_view({'delete': 'remove'})),
...
```

This is the URL I call `http://localhost:8000/heating/detail/6/`

But I don't understand why, i read the documentation, but find no clear explanation.

Can someone give me a hint about this issue?

Comment: Check this once. Similar issue it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711975/django-drf-405-method-not-allowed-on-delete-operation

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, but I do not understand what the mistake could be.

Comment: The above says that delete in django should always point to a specific resource.
In your case, the URL ends with a `/` thus making it act as a directory.

Comment: Thank you! for your fast and correct, goal-oriented information!