# Django Rest Framework: Using destroy with other params than pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering if it's possible to use destroy with other params on a GenericViewSet.

Like this : curl DELETE https://localhost/api/custom-url?first_param=123&second_param=1

instead of this : curl DELETE https://localhost/api/custom-url/1

I tried overriding destroy method but it didn't work:

```
class ExampleViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                         mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):

queryset = My_model.objects.all()
serializer_class = MySerializerSerializer

def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    first_param = kwargs.get('user_id')
    second_param = kwargs.get('season_id')

    try:
        instance = My_model.objects.get(first_field=first_param, second_field=second_param)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response({'message':'yes!!!'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Destroy works on the detail endpoint so if you want to delete many objects at once, add a custom list action for it.

Comment: @Ken4scholars no not really i just want to delete one instance

Comment: Then why not use the id? How can you be sure the filters will return a single result or that it will return any at all?

Comment: because id isn't really visible in the api. and also the two params are unique together so it's garanteed that the filter will return a single result

Comment: Then you just have to implement a custom action for that unique case.

Comment: To fix your destroy method you have to change the `kwargs.get` with `request.query_params.get`

Comment: check out that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637525/8548036  but use `request.query_params` instead of `kwargs`