# Django: delete requests returning error 405

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I have a small React/Django blog app and I'm trying to change the behavior on a DELETE request. Specifically I want to check if the post in the database has a field called "protected" equal to true or not, and fail if true.

At some point before this, deleting posts worked fine. When I overloaded the `destroy` method in `PostView` in `views.py` below, I noticed that it didn't work. The `destroy` method is never called - I never see the print statement inside. The server responds with a 405 and never calls `destroy`. Here's the error:

```
Method Not Allowed (DELETE): /api/posts/3
Method Not Allowed: /api/posts/3
[29/Nov/2020 17:03:04] "DELETE /api/posts/3 HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

If I remove my `destroy` method, it still doesn't work like it did previously, so I think I broke something unrelated. What am I missing?

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.urls import path, include, re_path                 
from rest_framework import routers
from server import views
from .views import index                        

router = routers.DefaultRouter()                      
router.register(r'posts', views.PostView, 'post')     

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', index, name='index'),           
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status

from .serializers import PostSerializer      
from .models import Post

from rest_framework.response import Response

from server.models import Post

class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
  serializer_class = PostSerializer          
  queryset = Post.objects.all()  

  def list(self, request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()  

    serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def update(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().filter(pk=pk)
    post = queryset[0]

    if post.protected == False:
      post.title = request.data['title']
      post.body = request.data['body']
      post.save()
      return Response("Post updated")
    else:
      return Response("Post protected", status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

  def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    print("In destroy!!!!!!!")
    queryset = Post.objects.all().filter(pk=pk)
    post = queryset[0]

    if post.protected == False:
      post.delete()
      return Response("Post deleted")
    else:
      return Response("Post protected", status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Here's where the delete request is made, in the React front end:

```
    axios.delete("/api/posts/" + postId)
        .then(post => dispatch(postDeleted(post)))
        .then(() => dispatch(fetchPosts()))
        .catch(errmess => dispatch(postDeleteFailed(errmess)));
```

Comment: please show your app's urls (router.urls)

Comment: Hi, 405 means the server does not allow such method. I think it is most likely related to the fact that in DRF, certain views cannot take ```DELETE``` method. check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711975/django-drf-405-method-not-allowed-on-delete-operation

Comment: I saw that post but nothing in it seems relevant. I added the CORS_ALLOW_METHODS list to explicity allow DELETE but there was no change. Also the urls.py file is above - it's the only one I use in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `urls` are overriding each other. And the problem is the regex pattern of `re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', index, name='index')`. and hence it redirects your request to wrong url and because that view does not support `DELETE` method it will return `405` status code (method not allowed). So you should delete this url, or change the regex of it (Because almost every patterns fall in it's category), or change your request url from `axios.delete("/api/posts/" + postId)` to `axios.delete("/api/posts/" + postId + '/')` (your url should have the trailing slash). I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting thank you! That was it. I put in the catch all so that any other page req would be directed to the front end, in case someone followed a link to the /about.html page without having loaded the front end app, for example, which wouldn't be redirected to the front end otherwise. I'll have to figure something else out. Thanks!