# Django - POST method error "POST /......./ HTTP/1.1" 405 0 with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I use the `POST` method since I need to change the database. But each time I used the `POST` method, this error occurred. Every time I click the button, the page will not be loading and saying `"POST /book/go-action/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`. There is no difference when I use `q = request.POST["quantity"]` or `q = request.POST.get('quantity', '')`. If I use `GET` method, the issue will not occur but the `GET` method cannot meet the needs. Also I don't need `action` in the form, cos I don't need the page to redirect to somewhere and I'm using ajax to call the function view. How can I fix the issue?

**Updated:**

The problem was caused by missing `action="{% url 'cart:add_to_cart' %}"`. But I don't want it to redirect to another page, that's why I'm using Ajax instead of using `action`. If using `action` then Ajax will become pointless I guess.

**book/detail.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            alert('clicked');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:add_to_cart" %}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#cartButton").text("Cart" + "(" + response.quantity + ")");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Got an error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="bookID" value=" {{ book.id }} " hidden>
    <button id="add" type="submit"> Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

**cart/views.py:**

```
def add_books(request):

    c = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # q = request.POST["quantity"]
        # book_id = request.POST["bookID"]

        q = request.POST.get('quantity', '')
        book_id = request.POST.get('bookID', '')

       # the rest of the code here         

        return JsonResponse(response)
```

**cart/urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_books/', views.add_books, name='add_to_cart')
]
```

**book/urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
 name='category_search'),
]
```

Comment: For changes in the database you should always use POST.

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes, I am using `POST` and mentioned that.

Comment: Yes I noted it, but you also say that you tried with GET, and GET is not how you send data to be saved in a database.

Comment: @guillermochamorro it's ok, do u know how to fix this problem and what causes this problem?

Comment: do you use django forms ?

Comment: @AbhijithK I don't, but if that works I'll try

Comment: I am not sure. Have you defined the URLs properly. Also the form action. See if this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your form submits and sends the request to `/book/go-action/`, which I assume is the route for the view the form is on, but the route that the POST should go to is `/add_books` as defined in your `urls.py`.

To fix this, you need to add an `action` attribute to your `<form>`. Here's an example:

```
<form method="post" action="/add_books"> {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="bookID" value=" {{ book.id }} " hidden>
    <button id="add" type="submit"> Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

**Edit**: Ajax Code (independent of my above code)

I think the main issue here is that while the `click` event function will work properly (as far as I can tell), after it executes, the submit event is still triggered and the default action ensues. To fix you need to add `event` as an argument to the function and call `preventDefault` on that `event` so that the default submit does not happen.

Here's what that looks like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:add_to_cart" %}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#cartButton").text("Cart" + "(" + response.quantity + ")");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Got an error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yeah I see, thanks. But I want it to stay in the same page instead of redirecting to another page once I add books. That's why I'm using Ajax. I'll upload my Ajax code as well.

Comment: @Jinx ah well if you can't get Ajax to work, you can have the `add_books` function return `HttpResponseRedirect('book/go-action')` so the user is kept on the current page.

Comment: sorry for bothering u really. cos I want to learn how to use ajax, and I think I may need it a lot in the future. Can u please take a look at my ajax code as well?

Comment: @Jinx yeah no worries. When you submit the form, do you get the expected behavior once before the error? Meaning is a book created? I'm wondering if the form is submitting twice

Comment: no, it can't load anything immediately after I press the button. `This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405`. And there is no change in the database.

Comment: @Jinx right but if you put a `print` statement in your `add_books` function can you see it being called twice in a row?

Comment: that's the other problem, I tried to print something as what you said. But PyCharm sucks, I can't see any output on the Python Console. On the terminal, it said `Method Not Allowed (POST): /book/swift-programming-big-nerd-ranch-guide/` and `Method Not Allowed: /book/swift-programming-big-nerd-ranch-guide/
`.

Comment: I added it. Now nothing happens if I click the button, the button does nothing.

Comment: ah sorry, I forgot the alert statement, the alert worked but the rest not working

Comment: @Jinx I think the line in the `success` handler may need a `$` at the beginning of it?

Comment: like `$success: function (response) `?, no difference hahaha can't be bothered

Comment: @Jinx like `$("#cartButton")`

Comment: ah yes sure, but the problem is that it is not submitting anything, no books added on the background. my view works fine (tested using `action`).

Comment: ah in the browser console it says `2(index):31 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):31)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)`

Comment: @Jinx yep that'll be it I think. It looks like you're using the slim build if jQuery, which I think does not support ajax, so you can just change to the normal build.

Comment: yeah now the `error` section worked, still need to work on it? how?

Comment: I tried this. `error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.quantity);
                    }`, then the alert says 'undefined'

Comment: @Jinx you'll need to log the response to see what it looks like and possibly check your servers logs and debug from there. However this is getting beyond the scope of the original question. If you can identify a new problem that you need help with, I'd suggestion starting a new question on SO