# Method Not Allowed (POST) Django 405 error

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-status-code-405

I've just changed my code from function based views to class based views and now am getting an error I can't seem to resolve.

The error appears when a user presses a button to submit their location coordinates.

`Method Not Allowed: /connect/post
[2019/02/11 14:27:17] HTTP POST /connect/post 405 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:57896]`

Everything was working before and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have both the `get and post` requests. Could someone point me in the right direction?

views.py

```
class ConnectView(View):
    template_name = 'connect/home.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'users': User.objects.exclude(username=request.user),
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        location = Location(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], 
longitude=request.POST['longitude'], user = request.user)
        location.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'success'})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', connect_views.ConnectView.as_view(), name='connect_home'),
]
```

connect.html

```
<script>
function showPosition(position) {
    pos = position;
    var { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
    $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled", null);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $demo = $("#demo");
    $('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
      var data = pos.coords;
      data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
      $.post("post", data, function() {
        alert("Location Confirmed!");
      });
    });
  });

</script>

---omitted irrelevant code--
<button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled>2. Confirm Location </button>
```

Comment: Are you sure that that is the right URL you are posting to (maybe it should be only `connect/`). Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584421/9225671) that has some pointers to check for usual causes for this kind of error.

Comment: Note to self: 405 errors are, most often than not, just 404 in disguise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are posting to the wrong URL (`connect/post/` instead of `connect/`). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22983222/9225671) has some pointers to check for usual causes of this error.

You could try by changing this line

```
$.post("post", data, function() {
```

to

```
$.post(window.location, data, function() {
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that was indeed the problem. What is the benefit of doing `window.location` over `$.post("", data, function() {` ? Cheers!

Comment: @Trillz Oh, does `$.post("", ...);` work as well? I did not know that. If it does work, then of course that is less code and probably a better option then.