# When overriding "perform_destroy" getting {"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, http-status-code-405

New to Django and trying to implement a REST api. 
Here is the code:

from views.py

```
class reg_event(generics.CreateAPIView):
     queryset = event_registration_stub.objects.all()
     serializer_class = serializers.EventRegistrationStubSerializer

     def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(parent_volunteer=self.request.user)


class reg_event_delete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
     queryset = event_registration_stub.objects.all()
     serializer_class = serializers.EventRegistrationStubSerializer

def perform_destroy(self, serializer):
    instance.delete(parent_volunteer=self.request.user, parent_event=self.kwargs["parent_event"])
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class  EventRegistrationStubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      parent_volunteer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='parent_volunteer.id')
     class Meta:
         model = event_registration_stub
         fields = ('id', 'parent_event', 'parent_volunteer')
```

And from urls.py

```
    url(r'^register_user_for_event/$', views.reg_event.as_view(), name='register_user_for_event'),
    url(r'^delete_user_for_event/$', views.reg_event_delete.as_view(), name='delete_user_for_event'),
```

register user for event works. However the following:

```
   curl -X POST -d "parent_event=1" -H 'Authorization: Token 21cc749c43bf80f27598987cd5a9926d988ba64c' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/delete_user_for_event/
```

returns

```
"POST /api/delete_user_for_event/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41
```

I tried looking at [405 POST method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed)

But I'm not sure what is wrong with my urls. Is my perform destroy incorrect? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send `destroy` request with curl, you should use:

`curl -X DELETE ...`

`generics.DestroyAPIView` has only delete method. That's why you get 405 error when sending post request