# Django url collisions

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-views, url-routing

Using Django==2.2.11, djangorestframework==3.8.1

Thank you for reading!

The urls I am using that have the collision:

```
urlpatterns = [
    . . . 
    url(
        r'^some-path$',
        views.MyViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
    ),
    url(
        r'^some-path$',
        views.MyViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}),
    ),
    ...
]
```

I am using postman to test each path, and it seems like there is a collision between these two urls.
Using this url with a GET, would work:

```
http://my_domain.com:8000/some-path
```

But POST with same url (and with a valid payload) would throw error:

```
WARNING 2020-03-28 19:13:57,288 "POST /some-path HTTP/1.1" 405 41
```

And response:

```
{"detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

I urls are swapped in order, then the POST would work, and GET would throw a similar error.

I looked at this post:
[405 POST method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed)

I would gladly add the view code - but I am pretty sure the issue is with the urls, since they each work when swapped order. 
Will add it upon request.

Thank you!

EDIT: I confused the urls- added the `retrieve` instead of `list` sorry!

Comment: I don't understand how URL collision will happen in your case since `POST /some-path` and `GET /some-path/<pk>` are different. (FYI: I tried to reproduce the issue, but I couldn't)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I mistakenly posted the wrong url for the GET - apologies
I fixed the question above, PTAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pointing to same end-point, ie **`/some-path`**, you should add your extra actions as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some-path$', MusicianViewset.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})),
]
```