# POST method works locally but not in production 405 (Method Not Allowed) - Nextjs

Tags: javascript, post, next.js, fetch-api, cloudinary

The code locally works perfectly but when I upload it to Vercel it gives me the error 405 (Method Not Allowed), the code stops working in the POST method, I checked everything and I really can't find a solution, I hope you can help me.

```
const data = new FormData();
      data.set("file", file);

const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
});
```

<kbd>=></kbd>
api/upload/route.ts

```
const data = await request.formData();

  const bytes = await data.get('file').arrayBuffer()
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes)

  const response : any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve(res)
    }).end(buffer)
  })
```

I hope it can be solved, because of many things and still nothing like it could also be Vercel but I uploaded my project to Netlify and it is the same.

Comment: see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed?rq=2 helps

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Check out your production logs!**

If you're using Vercel they are here:
[image: screenshot]

The actual error is probably not related to NextJS. It just fails without showing the actual error in the browser console (for safety reasons).

In my case the issue was a bug in the `sharp` library, that uses different binaries for linux and macos, and it wasn't loading the proper one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But 405 seems does not reach the application and thus no logs. It seems to be blocked by some proxy on vercel

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to directly pipe the raw file bytes, which Vercel blocks.

**Try this out:**
Encode the file to base64 before upload.

```js
const fileBuffer = await image.arrayBuffer();
var mime = image.type;
var encoding = 'base64';
var base64Data = Buffer.from(fileBuffer).toString('base64');
var fileUri = 'data:' + mime + ';' + encoding + ',' + base64Data;

try { 
    const uploadToCloudinary = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var result = cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileUri, { invalidate: true })
                .then((result) => {
                     console.log(result);
                     resolve(result); })
                .catch((error) => {
                     console.log(error);
                     reject(error);
                 });
            });
        }; 

    const result = await uploadToCloudinary();
    let imageUrl = result.secure_url;
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: Ok brother
This code
const data = await request.formData();

  const bytes = await data.get('file').arrayBuffer()
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes)

  const response : any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve(res)
    }).end(buffer)
  })
is trying to directly pipe the raw file bytes, which Vercel blocks and  using a POST request to Cloudinary. Vercel's serverless functions only allow GET and HEAD methods by default. POST requests will result 405 error

Comment: The explantation should be in the answer. Adding long code in a comment is also pointless and barely readable.

Comment: I have also included it in the answer, as mentioned previously.

Comment: Only a part. **All** the important details should be in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and this is how I went about fixing it.

If you are using fileupload from express-fileupload as a middleware, then my guess is that, that aspect is creating a temp file in your local environment whose location is not available in production.

However, you can create a /tmp/ path in your production simply by adding the directory parameters like this:

```
const router = createRouter()
  .use(
    fileUpload({
      useTempFiles: true,
      tempFileDir: "/tmp/",
    })
  );
```

before uploading to server.

I hope this fixes yours

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but I found a solution in the comments of  [Nextjs & Cloudinary - Subida de archivos a la nube](https://youtu.be/_Xkdn1QpPG0) . Check that your version of Next.js is not higher than 13.4.19. If you have a higher version, do a downgrade:

Unistall Next.js

```
npm uninstall next
```

Install Next.js 13.4.19

```
npm install next@13.4.19
```

> Make sure not to update the Next.js version in the security alerts.